# files in /home partition missing

Tags: partitioning

I installed ubuntu 14.04 alongside windows 7. During installation I set D drive for '/' and E drive for'/home'. I am very sure that I unticked format option for /home partition. I had very important files in E drive. After installation, I am not able to find those folders in both windows and ubuntu. Two partitions are also missing in windows. From where can I access my folders? . Its really important. Anyone please help me.

Answer (score 1):

First off, these are partition not drives. Did you back up your data?

Second, Windows can not read linux partitions without third part software being installed. This is why the two disappeared from windows.

Third, if these were NTFS partitions, Ubuntu formatted them both so it could install it's file system.

You can probably recover your partitions and files using recovery tools in Windows; howevver there will be data loss as some of the files were invariable overwritten by the install